# Is there a way to attach a template event based on the user role in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, handlebars.js

I was wondering, since I couldn't figure it out yet, if there's a way to attach a Meteor's template event, like:

```
Template.businessOperations.events({
    'dblclick .display': function (evt, tmpl) {
       //DO SOMETHING;
    }
}
```

Based on the current user's role.

For example:

```
if (Meteor.user().profile.type === 'admin') {
  Template.businessOperations.events({
      'dblclick .display': function (evt, tmpl) {
         //DO SOMETHING;
      }
  }
}
```

I've tried that and it didn't work, I've also tried getting the user from the actual event method and it didn't work either, I'm kind of not seeing the right solution here.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Keep in mind that the `profile` field is user editable by default.  (Its meant to store user-preference stuff)  So put your user "type" on the user object directly.  A relevant package which does this can be found here: https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles

Comment: Will take care of that, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding the event only when the user is an admin is tricky, because at the time the template code is evaluated, the user probably isn't logged in. Doing the check inside of the event handler, as you suggested, seems perfectly reasonable. I'd write it like:

```
Template.businessOperations.events({
  'dblclick .display': function() {
    if (Meteor.user() && (Meteor.user().profile.type === 'admin')) {
      console.log('double click and admin!');
    }
  }
});
```

I added the extra check for `Meteor.user()` to guard against the case where the user isn't logged in. You can remove it if that isn't a possibility.

Comment: I ask for Meteor.user().profile instead and it works.